# Trying to open a edit form to edit an object in Spring but returning a 404

Tags: java, spring, forms, get, dispatcher

I'm trying to create an edit form and prepopulate to form with the chosen objects values but it is returning an HTTP status of 404 and the error message I'm getting is

> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.noHandlerFound No
>   mapping for GET
>   /AgentsCRUD/agent/edit/1;jsessionid=07E2EC08848D0C9C9346DC67563DDF1F

I think what I have is pretty logical but I must have messed up with the mapping.

The code in the get AllAgent.jsp

```
 <spring:message code="welcome.message" /> 
<body>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
        <th align="left"><spring:message code="label.agentId" /></th>
         <th align="left"><spring:message code="label.name" /></th>
         <th align="left"><spring:message code="label.fax" /></th>
         <th align="left"><spring:message code="label.phone" /></th>
         <th align="left"><spring:message code="label.email" /></th>
         <th align="left"><spring:message code="label.datejoined" /></th>
         <th align="left"><spring:message code="label.sales" /></th>
         <th align="left"><spring:message code="label.actions" /></th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${agentList}" var="agent"> 
            <tr>
                <td>${agent.agentId}</td>
                <td>${agent.name}</td>
                <td>${agent.fax}</td>
                <td>${agent.phone}</td>
                <td>${agent.email}</td>

                <td>
                 <a href="\AgentsCRUD\agent\delete?agentId=${agent.agentId}"><spring:message code="label.delete" /></a>
                 <spring:url value="/agent/edit/${agent.agentId}" var="editURL"/>
                 <a href="${editURL}"><spring:message code="label.edit" /></a>
                 <a href="\AgentsCRUD\agent\add"><spring:message code="label.insert" /></a>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</body>
```

the code in the controller AgentController.java

```
      @GetMapping("/edit")
public ModelAndView EditAnAgent(@QueryParam("agentId") int agentId) {
    return new ModelAndView("/editAgent", "agent", service.getAgentById(agentId));
}


@GetMapping("/editAgent")
public ModelAndView editAgent(@Valid @ModelAttribute("agent") Agents a, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("/editAgent");
    }
    service.editAgent(a);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/agent");
}
```

the code in the Model AgentService.java

```
public static Agents getAgentByID(int agentId) {
    EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEMF().createEntityManager();
    Agents a = null;
    try {
        a = em.createNamedQuery("Agents.findByAgentId", Agents.class)
                .setParameter("agentId", (agentId))
                .getSingleResult();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error in getting property details: " + ex);
    } finally {
        em.clear();
    }
    return a;
}

public void editAgent(Agents a) {
    EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEMF().createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();

    try {
        transaction.begin();
        em.merge(a);
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

the code in the editAgent.jsp

```
   <form:form method="POST" action="/AgentsCRUD/agent/editAgent" modelAttribute="agent">

  <table>
            <tr> 
                <td><form:label path="agentId"><spring:message code="label.agentId" /></form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="agentId"/></td> 
                <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="agentId"/> </td>
           </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="name"><spring:message code="label.name" /></form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
                <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="name"/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="phone"><spring:message code="label.phone" /></form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="phone"/></td>
                <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="phone"/> </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="fax"><spring:message code="label.fax" /></form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="fax"/></td>
                <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="fax"/> </td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td><form:label path="email"><spring:message code="label.email" /></form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="email"/></td>
                <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="email"/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="username"><spring:message code="label.username" /></form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="username"/></td>
                <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="username"/> </td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><form:label path="password"><spring:message code="label.password" /></form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="password"/></td>
                <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="password"/> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <spring:message code="submit.button" var="labelSubmit"></spring:message>
                <td><input type="submit" value="${labelSubmit}"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</body>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Error the url given is .../edit/1 where 1 is a path parameter,

However in the get mapping, you are trying to read it as a query parameter.

Try this.

```
@GetMapping("/edit/{agentId}")
Patient getEmployee(@PathParam("agentId") int agentId) ;
```